# iOS app with lots of different Views

Tags: ios, ios5, view

I'm developing an iOS app that I want it to have more than 10 views. In Android, you must create a layout and then its Class. I've been trying to achieve this in XCode but I do not know how to do it...

The idea is to have a class for view so that every class manages its own view. What I've done so far is this:

1- Create a new Objective-C class named Overview and subclass UIViewController and then check Witch XIB for user interface.

2- To show that view I use: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Overview" owner:self options:nil];`

3- And in the viewDidLoad I use this: `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"overview_portrait.jpg"]];` to change the background image

I can see the view but the background doesn't change, and when I add buttons and I click them it throws error: `-[ViewController push:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7427220`

How can achieve what I want?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are showing the view but you are not loading its controller, that's why the controller's methods are not getting called. You have to create an instance of your controller class and push it from your current controller. Something like this:

```
Overview *overview = [[Overview alloc] initWithNibName:@"Overview" bundle:nil];
[self pushViewController:overview animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you! Where do I have to put that piece of code? I'm starting in iOS development...

Comment: This code present/push a new controller from the current controller, the place to put it depend on the problem you are solving, you has to give us more details about it to be able to answer this question, additionally, are you using storyboards or are you creating a nib based app?

Answer (score 0):

Pushing ViewControllers is for Navigation Controllers, so if you are looking at interface builder if your screen View (Im not sure if your using storyboards or XIBs) if the view you can change is attached to a grey box labeled "Navigation Controller" then you can use:

```
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:myNewViewInstance animated:YES];
```

with the background image you are better using:

```
UIImageView *myBackground = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width)];
            [self.view addSubview:myBackground];
            [self.view sendSubviewToBack:myBackground];
```

If you are not using navigational controllers you can use:

```
        [self presentModalViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#];(BOOL)#>];
```

this will present the new viewcontroller and then to go back use:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:<#(BOOL)#>];
```

For lots of views, i find storyboards is best, when creating a new project tick the use storyboard box, then you can see all your views easily and create modal transitions through button pushes and what not using CTRL+Click and drag from a button on `view1` and unDrag anywhere on `view2` and click modal, this will then let you transition.

Comment: Thank you! Where do I have to put that piece of code? I'm starting in iOS development...

Comment: well if you are trying to navigate different screens the presentModalViewController would go in a but or at the end of a specific event.

For the dismissModalViewController, this would go at the end of an event in the screen you previously presented.

the background could go anywhere viewDidLoad? -(BOOL)viewWillAppear

but i woul dsuggest reading this little tutorial which is quick and gets into storyboarding transitions quick and easy

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: I've been reading that tutorial and I've seen that storyboard is more about linking the views as a 'story' and in my app I want to access all the view from any other view. Example: I've 5 views: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. In story board I have to access the following way: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 if I'm not wrong and what I want is: 1 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5 -> 2 -> 4 -> 3... Can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the setup of Android, but for iOS, you want to instantiate the view controllers, not the nib file. What you want to do is create a new overview class and initialize it with the nib.

```
Overview *overviewController = [[Overview alloc] initWithNibName:@"Overview" bundle:nil];
```